# apt-get trying to connect to unknown IP

Tags: bash, shell, apt

Cofession: I am just a noobie with shell and networking so sorry if this is some sort of blunder!

apt-get doesnt seem to work in my shell. It seems to be trying to connect to an IP (10.6.1.57) which doesnt even respond to a ping.

This is what happens when i try apt-update:
0% [Connecting to 10.6.1.57 (10.6.1.57)] [Connecting to 10.6.1.57 (10.6.1.57)]
{This seems to go on for a long time}

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```html
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Check if any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` have this IP hard-coded. Or maybe your DNS is giving this IP while resolving some host names.

Comment: Do you use a proxy server?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What's the output to `grep -R "10.6.1.57" /etc/apt` ?

Comment: Thanks!!! The IP was there hardcoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ for list files containing that ip.

Comment: Nope, grep didnt find any files with the given IP in sources.list.d

Comment: Sorry, got it!! thnkz

Answer (score 5):

Check this file too: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00apt-cacher-proxy` maybe there is some proxy as it was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I only changed one thing to get it working. Added "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to /etc/resolve.conf and it worked good

Answer (score 0):

That can be both custom repository address and APT proxy override configuration. They can be set in several locations under `/etc/apt/`.

Resolve address 10.6.1.57 into host name (e.g. with `host 10.6.1.57`) and then search for both IP and host name in the whole `/etc/apt/` directory.

```
grep -r 10.6.1.57 /etc/apt/
```

In my case it was custom `Acquire::http::Proxy` setting in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.